# how to use Flask with multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, flask, python-multiprocessing

Concretely, I'm using Flask to process a request, pseudocode like this:

```py
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/foo", methods=["POST"])
def foo():
    data = request.get_json()  # {"request_id": "abc", "data": "some text"}
    result_a = do_task_a(data)  # returns {"result_a": "a"}, maybe about 1 second to finish 
    result_b = do_task_b(data)  # returns {"result_b": "b"}, maybe about 1 second to finish
    result_c = do_task_c(data)  # returns {"result_c": "c"}, maybe about 1 second to finish
    result = {
        "result_a": result_a["result_a"],
        "result_b": result_b["result_b"],
        "result_c": result_c["result_c"]}
    return result

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=4000, threaded=False)
```

Here, `do_task_a`, `do_task_b`, `do_task_c` are completely independent subtasks, I know I can use `multiprocessing.Process` to create processes to finish these three subtasks, and use `join()` to wait for subtask done, But I don't know it's proper way to create `Process` for every request?

Maybe I can use `multiprocessing.Queue` to help, But I don't find a good way.

I search for multiprocessing, but can't figure out a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a python guy, but indeed creating processes is sn expensive operation
If its possible - create threads they're cheaper than processes.

If you run the request multiple times - you can do even better than that, because creating threads per request is still quite expensive

Even more advanced setup is to create a "pre-loaded" thread pool. Like N threads that you always keep in memory ready for running arriving task.

In terms of technical solution I've found [This article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/concurrency_in_python/concurrency_in_python_pool_of_threads.htm) that explains how to create thread pools in python 3.2+